# When coolant is mixed with various temperatures of water, why does the coolant specific heat capacity change?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

I'm doing a lab for my Grade 12 Chemistry class and the experiment involves mixing a coolant with water at 40, 50 and 60 degrees Celsius, and recording the final temperature of the mixture. From there, we are to calculate the specific heat capacity of the coolant to ultimately prove that SHC is an intensive property. My observations have been as follows:

Water= 40℃, SHC of coolant= 6.305J/g℃; Water= 50℃, SHC of coolant=3.872J/g℃; Water=60℃, SHC of coolant=2.562J/g℃

Thus, the results showed that as the water temperature increased, the specific heat capacity of the coolant decreased. Logically, this makes sense as the water would be able to heat up the coolant using less energy if it's hotter. However, I can't form a scientific explanation. Could someone describe what is happening here at a molecular level, in Grade 12 Chemistry-level terms?

Comment: Your change in heat capacity with temperature seems excessive.  There are at least two possible reasons:  1) there is some error in your measurements or calculations;  2) the water and coolant mix in a highly non-ideal way that invalidates your attempt to measure the heat capacity of the coolant.  And note that your experiment implicitly assumes that ideal mixing is involved.

Comment: Describe in details how you reached the final numbers, so responders can evaluate why your numbers look like if SHC changes so much. Have you included heat capacity of device? Have you tried mixing coolant and water of the same temperature, if mixture gets warmed up ?  ( E.g. ethanol and water do)